# Add styles to only sticky elements with react-table-sticky

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am using `react-table-sticky` to make my columns sticky, now I am trying to add styles (border-right) to table elements which are `sticky`. When I inspect sticky elements, they don't have specific classnames for sticky elements but instead `data-sticky-td="true"`. I can't find a way to add styles only to them. You can see my code sandbox sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-snow-x1ytd?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

I added a classname by checking if that cell has a sticky value and it works.

```
                ..
                  {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                    <TableCell
                      {...cell.getCellProps()}
                      className={`${
                        cell.column.sticky === "left"
                          ? "left-sticky-cell"
                          : cell.column.sticky === "right"
                          ? "right-sticky-cell"
                          : ""
                      }`}
                    >
                      {cell.render("Cell")}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                 ..
```